# Help me identify the cable for this

Tags: connector, signal, cables

I am trying to find the audio cable for my sub system but I can't find it and don't even know its name.

I would appreciate your assistance.

[image: sub system connector]

Comment: are you asking about the connector or about a cable assembly?

Answer (score 1):

It's a mini-DIN-9 connector, and the cable (at this end) would be a male one.

Comment: Note that knowing this connector doesn't tell us anything about what connector goes on the other end or how it's connected to this end, though. The other end is probably also 9-pin mini-DIN, probably connected straight through (that is, pin 1 to pin 1, 2 to 2, and so on), but it could be anything.

Comment: Exactly what I intended with the **(at this end)** :)

Comment: Yes, I was clarifying that for the asker's sake.